# Is the limsup or liminf of n-wise independent events independent?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space.

Consider events indexed by $m, n \in \mathbb N$:

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ A_{1,n}, A_{2,n}, A_{3,n} ...$ are n-wise independent.

$A_{m,1}: A_{1,1}, A_{2,1}, A_{3,1}, ...$ are 1-wise independent.

$A_{m,2}: A_{1,2}, A_{2,2}, A_{3,2}, ...$ are 2-wise independent.

$A_{m,3}: A_{1,3}, A_{2,3}, A_{3,3}, ...$ are 3-wise independent.

$\vdots \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ddots$

Do we eventually have mutual independence if we let n increase?

$\lim_n A_{m,n}$ does not necessarily exist, but we can define:

$$CI_m := \liminf_n A_{m,n}$$

$$CS_m := \limsup_n A_{m,n}$$

1. Are $CI_1, CI_2, ...$ independent?

How about some subsequence $CI_{m^{*}}, CI_{m^{*}+1}, ...$ or $CI_{f(1)}, CI_{f(2)}$ for $f(m): \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$?

2. Are $CS_1, CS_2, ...$ independent?

How about some subsequence $CS_{m^{*}}, CS_{m^{*}+1}, ...$ or $CS_{f(1)}, CS_{f(2)}$ for $f(m): \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$?

---

**Column sums:**

$\forall m \in \mathbb N, P(A_{m,1}) + P(A_{m,2}) + ... \le \infty$.

If we can find an $m^{*} \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $A_{m^{*},1}, A_{m^{*},2}, ...$ are at least pairwise independent, then by the Borel 0-1 Law, we have that $P(\limsup_n A_{m,n}) = 0$ or $1$ for $m \ge m^{*}$.

Hence, $CS_{m^{*}}, CS_{m^{*} + 1}, CS_{m^{*} + 2}, ...$ are independent.

If $m^{*} = 1$, then $CS_1, CS_2, ...$ are independent.

Is that right? How can we prove or disprove the existence of such a $m^{*}$?

---

**Row sums:**

Not sure if this helps, but meanwhile it seems that $\forall n \ge 2, P(A_{1,n}) + P(A_{2,n}) + ... \le \infty$ and the $A_{1,n}, A_{2,n}, ...$'s are at least pairwise independent.

If so, then by the Borel 0-1 Law, we have that $P(\limsup_m A_{m,n}) = 0$ or $1$ for $n \ge 2$.

Hence, we can define

$$RI_n := \liminf_m A_{m,n}$$

$$RS_n := \limsup_m A_{m,n}$$

$RS_2, RS_3, RS_4, ...$ are independent.

---

Possibly related: [Stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix)

?

Comment: I'm not sure what explains either downvotes or votes to close, but the post might garner a better reception if some more context or motivation were provided.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Elaborated. No context or motivation. Just something I thought. Although thinking about it more, it looks like those transition matrices or Markov something

Comment: Do you assume that the rows are independent? If so the answer is yes.

Comment: @OriGurel-Gurevich No, but thanks anyway. :( Interesting proposition. I think I'll try to prove that as well. Wait yes to 1 and 2 if the rows are independent as well? I think yes to 2 because of Borel 0-1 Law but yes to 1 also?

Comment: If the rows are independent then the answer to 1 and 2 is yes, simply because the liminf or limsup of a sequence belongs to the tail sigma-algebra. If the rows are not independent, then I'm pretty sure a counterexample can be constructed.

Comment: @OriGurel-Gurevich Ah right Kolmogorov 0-1 Law for both. Thanks ^-^ Going to wait for a counterexample then

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample. Since this question is more restrictive than [the sequel](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229136/do-we-have-independence-if-we-let-the-indices-of-the-events-increase), it is a counterexample to that, too.

Let $\{1,2,3,4\}$ have equal probability.

Let $1 \in A_{1,n},A_{2,n}$.

Let $2 \in A_{1,2k},A_{2,2k+1}$.

Let $3 \in A_{1,2k+1},A_{2,2k}$.

Then $A_{1,n}$ is independent of $A_{2,n}.$ Each has probability $1/2$ and the intersection has probability $1/4$.

In the tail $\sigma$-algebra, $CI_1 =CI_2 = \{1\}$, and $CS_1=CS_2 = \{1,2,3\}$, and these are not independent.